# Ansible dynamically assigned variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Unable to print the output of a variable when assigned in playbook. it returns the value of variable.

```yaml
    - name: get contents of local file
      set_fact:
        "{{ item.filename }}": "{{ lookup('file', 'files/conf/{{ item.name }}.zip') }}"
      loop: "{{ genericconf }}"

    - name: encode to base64
      set_fact:
        "{{ item.basename }}": "{{ '{{ item.filename }}' |b64encode }}"
      loop: "{{ genericconf }}"

    - name: add lines
      blockinfile:
        block: |4
                 "{{ {{ item.basename')} }}"
        path: "/opt/try/{{ item.name }}.name"
        insertafter: "configuration: >-"
        marker: ""
      loop: "{{ genericconf }}"
```

assign a variable to output of dictionary and try to call the value

results in jinja template error

Comment: use a dictionary rahter than trying to do somehting like dynamic names. then just look up the dict using the keys

Comment: the genericconf is a dictionary of items genericconf:
  - {name: "log4j", basename: "log4hb64", filename: "log4jf"}
  - {name: "encryption", basename: "encryption64", filename: "encrypf"}

Comment: When ever you find your self wanting you use dynamic variable names you almost always want a dictionary instead

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε all right, but still: [moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)